# Converting string to string array saving the spaces which are part of the word Java

Tags: java, split

How do I convert a string to a string array if the spaces between the characters are part of the word?

What I have:

```java
String phoneNumbers = "987-123-4567 123 456 7890 (123) 456-7890";
```

What I want it to be:

```java
String[] numbers = {"987-123-4567", "123 456 7890", "(123) 456-7890"};
```

When I'm trying to split:

```java
String[] array = phoneNumbers.split(" ");
```

The result is :

```java
[987-123-4567, 123, 456, 7890, (123), 456-7890]
```

Comment: Interesting question but don't think there any way to distinguish between the space used in 987-123-4567 123 and in 123 456. May be you iterate the string as char array and split when you have found 9 digits.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

You may use a regex, then with a matcher you can find iteratively the matches in the string

```java
String phoneNumbersString = "987-123-4567 123 456 7890 (123) 456-7890";
String regex = "(\\d{3}-\\d{3}-\\d{4})|(\\d{3}\\s\\d{3}\\s\\d{4})|(\\(\\d{3}\\)\\s\\d{3}-\\d{4})";

List<String> phoneNumbersList = new ArrayList<>();
Matcher m = Pattern.compile(regex).matcher(phoneNumbersString);
while (m.find()) {
    phoneNumbersList.add(m.group());
}
```